# Uptime command misconception with suspend and resume states

Tags: command-line, proc, time, uptime

The definition for uptime is "Tell how long the system has been running." but if you change your system power state to suspend or resume:

```
# uptime
 09:50:33 up  8 min, 2 users,  load average: 0,24, 0,33, 0,15
# pm-suspend
(5 minutes later, turning on again)
# uptime
 09:55:15 up  13 min, 2 users,  load average: 0,33, 0,33, 0,16
# pm-hibernate
(5 minutes later, turning on again)
# uptime
 10:01:16 up  19 min, 2 users,  load average: 3,77, 1,14, 0,43
```

The system hasn't been running but the uptime time counter increases.

Using the term ["wall time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time) or ["elapsed real time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time) in their definition instead of "has been running" can be the right approach nowadays?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `uptime` shows the elapsed wall-clock time since the system booted rather than the amount of time the system has spent running. (The boot date and time can be seen with `uptime -s` on Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how long the system has actually been running excluding the time spent sleeping, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532416/332937